# Can't insert data into sql db using java's SqlConnection

Tags: sqlconnection

I'm trying to insert data into a table an sql database, here's my code :

```java
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=GREGJAMES\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Hotel;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Guest Info Values ('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Reserved!");
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

But, i get the following error :

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing is your table name is "Guest Info" it should be [Guest Info] if it has whitespace.
Edit: making a bit of a leap here. Presuming your table is called just guest.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Guest (Info) Values ('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i tried it and still the same outcome

Comment: Specify the name of the columns in the insert

Comment: My tables and columns are all named the right way my good sir

Comment: From the above your SQL is incorrect. As I have know knowledge of the schema all I can do is guess...

Comment: Also you need to open your dB connection.

Answer (score 0):

Need to open connection and  Remove space between table name

```
cmd.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
{
    MessageBox.Show("Reserved!");
}
```

and

```
 cmd.CommandText = "insert into GuestInfo Values ('" + textBox1.Text +
 "')";
```

Comment: same outcome my sir